# Shout out to linux gurus. Permission exception

Tags: java, linux, printing, permissions, wildfly

I have a thermal printer that I am trying to configure with my Raspberry Pi 3b. I have a Wildfly server running a java app and I am trying to use [this driver](https://github.com/fintrace/tspl2-driver/blob/master/README.md) to communicate with the printer using the TSPL language.

Whenever I try to call connect I get an exception saying Permission denied: not enough privileges.

I tried to add a new permission in `/lib/udev/rules.d`

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="20d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="7001", MODE="0666", GROUP="wildfly"
```

And then run `udevadm control --reload-rules` to reload the rules but still no success.

I even tried to run:

```
sudo chown -R wildfly:wildfly /dev/usb/lp0
```

But still no success. Any help would be really appreciated at this moment. My printer is the HPRT LPQ58.

If I manually send commands to the /dev/usb/lp0 with the cat command those work, but with java I am not able to connect to the usb port.

Comment: [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found the problem. After a reboot it worked. It seems that

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

does not reload the rules if the printer is already plugged in the usb, so you either have to unplug and plug it back in or run:

```
udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
```